# How does the client decide which Concrete factory class it should use?

Tags: design-patterns, factory

Suppose that I have the following classes (I use AbstractFactory)

- a Client class,
- an Abstractfactory
- a Concrete1factory
- a Concrete2factory
- an AbstractProduct
- a Concrete1Product
- a Concrete2Product.

I want my client to know which factory class it should use. But how? 
I know I can use reflection if I knew the class name. But in my situation I will know some property other than classname. I can still associate the property with a classname to use reflection..

**Is there a good way without using switch or if ?**

In all the examples I saw, the client directly calls the factory method and gets the appropriate product but how ?  They didn't write the implementation details...

Comment: Can you provide some detail on the kind of property you have that's not the class name?  I wouldn't want to use reflection to do this, but to provide a reasonable answer I would need to know the nature of the property you know.  What's wrong with a switch or an if?  (I'm not saying that these are good choices, but I need to see the context.)

Comment: I think that if your client needs to know which factory it should use, then an Abstract Factory is the wrong choice of design pattern. Wouldn't a FactoryMethod with a parameter be a better solution?

Comment: Hi David,This is part of a design patterns course assignment and my teacher does not (really) like switch and if. Property realy does not have importance I just wanted to look out if there is a clever answer for the problem other than reflection.

Comment: Hi There are family of objects so I preferred abstract factory to factory method. Each time I look ı change something. Maybe I have to think about it more.. Thank you to both of you

Comment: If your teacher doesn't like `if` then I am not sure about his qualifications. Because `if` and `loop` are essential constructs in programming. When you have abstract factory, you need to give something to the factory that will determine what to build for you. This is why dependency injection is so popular - you can determine in XML which objects to pair on which call.